# Accesing DOM element

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

This can be a very basic question, but I'm really stuck.

I need to get out the values out of this element:

[image]

But I get stuck here, and can´t access to every pair key/value individually:

```
 alert(info.draggedEl.dataset.event);
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `info.draggedEl.dataset.event` is a JSON string. You need to parse JSON with `JSON.parse(info.draggedEl.dataset.event)` which will return a JS object.

Comment: As per [ask] please never post pictures of code, data or error messages. Include all such content as text. See also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, that solved my problem. And I take account of not posting pictures anymore. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the need of `JSON.parse()`, once this is done, you will be able to access the data. Here's what it looks like from a code perspective.

```
const data = JSON.parse('{\"title\": \"uno\"}'
console.log(data)
// Output: {title: 'uno'}

console.log(data.title)
// Output: uno
```